# Where does maven take the default version of findbugs?

Tags: maven, findbugs

I'm trying to make Maven use a specific version of `findbugs` when running

```
mvn findbugs:findbugs
```

It seems to ignore whatever version I set inside the POM. I tried running it using just a test POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
</project>
```

-which just seems to use findbugs version 2.5.2 by default. Where did this version come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the latest version of the plugin. see [Maven central repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfindbugs-maven-plugin)

`findbugs:findbugs` refer to `org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs:findbugs`

**Other refs:**

- [MOJO Production Plugins](http://mojo.codehaus.org/plugins.html#Production_Plugins)
- [FindBugs Maven Plugin' project page](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/)